# java eclipse patched JRE classes Xbootclasspath Could not find or load main class

Tags: java, eclipse

I have modified some core java classes for my own needs eg. using a cache for regexps in Java.lang.String match method.

I want to use these patched classes instead of the default classes in rt.jar that ship with the jre.

I have imported the src.zip sources into eclipse that contains all of the source files of the class files in rt.jar and changed them for my needs. I have then removed rt.jar from the eclipse JRE library config and changed the default VM arguments option for the installed JRE in eclipse to tell the VM to use my own custom core classes>

> -Xbootclasspath/p: /media/SSD/workspace/proj/bin/

however when running a simple test program the VM fails to boot with the following>

> "Could not find or load main class .media.SSD.workspace.proj.bin."

I also tried using -Xbootclasspath/a: to append instead but it makes no difference.

all the core java classes are in the bin folder with correct directory structure (compiled by eclipse) eg, java/util,java/io etc.

I don't know why it's complaining about a main class as the JRE libraries don't have one and my own main method for the project is in bin/core/boot.class which is detected and set by eclipse in run configurations (and worked fine before).

I was following this guide, which might be a bit out of date and does not use eclipse to patch the core classes>

http://media.techtarget.com/tss/static/articles/content/CovertJava/Sams-CovertJava-15.pdf

could someone point out what i'm doing wrong?

Update/Workaround: 
I created a new project with all the core classes then exported it as a new rt.jar file and put it in place of the default one in the jre/lib folder of openjdk and it works. But this means ALL java apps on my machine will use the patched classes rather than just my project which is far from ideal so my question above remains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be no whitespace in your parameter

```
-Xbootclasspath/p:/media/SSD/workspace/proj/bin/
```

The parameter to bootclasspath (after `:`) should be a `;` (on Windows) delimited list of folders zips and jars.

Java has interpreted your parameters as empty list of folders to prepend to bootclasspath and a name of class to run, that is why it is complaining that it cannot find class `.media.SSD.workspace.proj.bin.`

Comment: how to handle folder with spaces (except from renaming)?

Comment: Wrap the whole param in `""`. For instance `"-Xbootclasspath/p:/path/with space"`.